# applying jQuery UI dialog to classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Having some trouble getting this example to work with classes. I would like to have classes each bring up a separate dialog box with different information in them when they are clicked...https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4oswjz30/) is my fiddle and code.

HTML...

```
<div class="foo">click me
  <div class="bar">blahblahblah</div>
</div>

<div class="foo">or me
  <div class="bar">blahblahblah</div>
</div>
```

jQuery...

```
$( function() {
    $( ".bar" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( ".foo" ).click(function() {
      $(this).find(".bar").dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be able to use jquery UI Dialog using a class to open dialog as the way in your code because `$(this).find(".bar")` will return empty and does not exist.

Try using an id for inner div elements.

```
<div class="foo" data-id="x1" >click me
  <div class="bar" id="x1" >blahblahblah X1</div>
</div>

<div class="foo" data-id="x2" >or me
  <div class="bar" id="x2" >blahblahblah X2</div>
</div>
```

--

```
$( function() {
    $( ".bar" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      show: {
        effect: "blind",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });

    $( ".foo" ).click(function() {
      var id = $(this).data("id");
      $('#'+id).dialog( "open" );
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4oswjz30/2/)

Comment: Can it be done without id's? I would like to find another way to go without dynamically assigning id's in my html if possible